# Is "having a bowl" an idiom?

Tags: idioms

I'm translating an article about a Student Union that was remodeled and expanded. A section is titled "Having a 'Bowl'". This part tells about the expansion- two extra bowling lines for Game Center and a relocated wall. Is the word 'bowl' related to the bowling lines, or is it an idiom?

Answer (score 5):

Having a [**BALL**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+ball) is an idiom for having a good time.

Having a *BOWL* is a play on words

Comment: ... a curve ball.

Comment: Throwing one :)

Comment: Or smoking one.

Comment: or having the balls